# Django : Trouble facing registering 'User' model in the 'simple_history' package

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

**Scenario:**

I am using the [simple_history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package in Django.

In the documentation, in advanced usage part the "[History for a Third-Party Model](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#history-for-a-third-party-model)" it says,

> " To track history for a model you didn’t create, use the simple_history.register utility. You can use this to track models from third-party apps you don’t have control over.  Here’s an example of using simple_history.register to history-track the User model from the django.contrib.auth app"

So I put that code in the models.py (and tried admin.py too) as below:

```
from simple_history import register
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

register(User)
```

**Problem**:
When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` it gives the following error:

```
E:! Project\CMIT\CMITv0101\cmit001>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'auth':
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0009_historicaluser.py
- Create model HistoricalUser
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 193, in handle
self.write_migration_files(changes)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 232, in write_migration_files
with io.open(writer.path, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations\0009_histo
ricaluser.py'
```

What can I do now to register my User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error description, you do not have permission to make changes in the folder C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations

Change the permission of the folder to read, write and execute. Once done, run`python manage.py makemigrations`

Also, you are trying to make migrations in system packages. You can create custom User model in a separate app and then make migrations there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I want to register the base User model (auth.user) here, as instructed on document.